# R summarize at the top level by ungrouping date

Tags: r

I have an R code where Iam trying to summarize the code without ungrouping the time but R is not able to ungroup time.

My table looks like this

```
Time    |Zone          |Main Station    |Sum of Value
25/03/2019 00:30    |BW1    |BANW   |4 
25/03/2019 00:30    |BW2    |BANW   |4 
25/03/2019 00:30    |BW3    |BANW   |4 
25/03/2019 00:30    |BW4    |BANW   |4 
25/03/2019 01:30        |BW1     |BANW    |2
25/03/2019 01:30        |BW3    | BANW  |  6.6
25/03/2019 01:30        |BW2    | BANW  |  7.2
25/03/2019 01:30        |gh1    | ty |  2
25/03/2019 01:30        |gh2     |ty   | 6.6
25/03/2019 01:30        |gh3    |ty   | 7.2
```

I am trying to get a table like this

```
Time              |Main Station |Sum of Value
25/03/2019 00:30        |BANW      |16  
25/03/2019 01:30       | BANW       |9.2
```

I am trying to find the sum of the all the zones for individual stations for each time stamp.

When I am summarizing , the output is in the form of Zone rather than the station name and Pivot is saying unable to sum time as I don't want to group by time rather than keep time as it is and only sum the zone values for individual stations.

Also tried converting the time into hour format using the lubridate package but output is still in the form of Zone and warning comes up about the tibble.

Comment: Can you please include in your question a sample of your data using `dput(YOUR_DATA)`? This will let us load the data in the same form that you have it.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about your goal: your table seems to show totals by Time and station, but your question then says you want "to sum the zone values for individual stations"?  What code are you referring to related to "Pivot"?

Comment: Using `dplyr`, I would presume you want something like  `your_data %>% group_by(Time, 'Main Station') %>% summarize('Sum of Value' = sum('Sum of Value')`

Comment: Please show us the code you’re using, the actual error message you get, and a representative sample of your data using the `dput` function. Otherwise we can only guess what you’re trying to do and what’s going wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset$Time <- as.character(dataset$Time)
dataset%>%group_by(Time,Main Station)%>%summarise(Sum of Value=sum(Sum of Value))
```

the above code will work as per your requirement.